# I want to combine 2 different java scripts

Tags: javascript

I have 2 java script codes, one work as a search suggestion and second is for adding another form fields dynamically and this second script also calculate values given in input fields, but both scripts have this 'ADD MORE PRODUCT' feature. What i want is; i want to combine both 'ADD more" feature, because 1st script works on id="" tag to identify field to show search result but second script not do it.

[image]

Fetching details in first row is successful, but when i click ADD more button populated by second script, it does not work

```js
//Script to fetch details based on search box :

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('keydown', '.prname', function() {

    var id = this.id;
    var splitid1 = id.split('_');
    var index1 = splitid1[1];

    $('#' + id).autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "getDetails.php",
          type: 'post',
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            search: request.term,
            request: 3
          },
          success: function(data) {
            response(data);
          }
        });
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
        var prid = ui.item.value; // selected id to input

        // AJAX
        $.ajax({
          url: 'getDetails.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            prid: prid,
            request: 4
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response) {

            var len = response.length;

            if (len > 0) {
              var id = response[0]['id'];
              var fprice = response[0]['fprice'];
              var packing = response[0]['packing'];
              var pweight = response[0]['pweight'];

              document.getElementById('fprice_' + index1).value = fprice;
              document.getElementById('packing_' + index1).value = packing;
              document.getElementById('pweight_' + index1).value = pweight;

            }

          }
        });

        return false;
      }
    });
  });

  // Add more
  $('#addmore').click(function() {

    // Get last id 
    var lastname_id = $('.tr_input input[type=text]:nth-child(1)').last().attr('id');
    var split_id = lastname_id.split('_');

    // New index
    var index = Number(split_id[1]) + 1;

    // Create row with input elements
    var html = "<tr class='tr_input'><td><input type='text' class='name' id='name_" + index + "' placeholder='Enter name'></td><td><input type='text' class='phone' id='phone_" + index + "' ></td><td><input type='text' class='address' id='address_" + index + "' ></td><td><input type='text' class='custid' id='custid_" + index + "' ></td></tr>";

    // Append data
    $('tbody').append(html);

  });
});



// Second script to do calculation :

$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $("#add_row").click(function() {
    b = i - 1;
    $('#addr' + i).html($('#addr' + b).html()).find('td:first-child').html(i + 1);
    $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
    i++;
  });
  $("#delete_row").click(function() {
    if (i > 1) {
      $("#addr" + (i - 1)).html('');
      i--;
    }
    calc();
  });

  $('#tab_logic tbody').on('keyup change', function() {
    calc();
  });
  $('#tax').on('keyup change', function() {
    calc_total();
  });


});

function calc() {
  $('#tab_logic tbody tr').each(function(i, element) {
    var html = $(this).html();
    if (html != '') {
      var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
      var price = $(this).find('.fprice').val();
      var discount = $(this).find('.discount').val();
      $(this).find('.total').val((qty * price) - discount);

      calc_total();
    }
  });
}

function calc_total() {
  total = 0;
  $('.total').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  $('#sub_total').val(total.toFixed(2));
  tax_sum = total / 100 * $('#tax').val();
  $('#tax_amount').val(tax_sum.toFixed(2));
  $('#total_amount').val((tax_sum + total).toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style='border-collapse: collapse;' id="tab_logic">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">#</th>
      <th class="text-center"> Product </th>
      <th width="190px" class="text-center"> Price </th>
      <th width="30px" class="text-center"> Price for </th>
      <th width="100px" class="text-center"> Packing </th>
      <th width="80px" class="text-center"> Qty </th>
      <th width="100px" class="text-center"> Discount </th>
      <th width="150px" class="text-center"> Total </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='tr_input' id='addr0'>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input type="text" name='product[]' id="prname_1" class="prname form-control" /></td>

      <td>
        <input type="number" name='price[]' id='fprice_1' class="form-control fprice price" step="0.00" min="0" />
      </td>
      <td><input style="width:70px" type="text" class="pweight input-group-text" id="pweight_1"></td>

      <td><input type="text" name='pack[]' class="form-control packing" id='packing_1' step="0" min="0" /></td>

      <td><input type="text" name='qty[]' class="form-control qty" id="qty_1" step="0" min="0" /></td>

      <td><input type="text" name='discount[]' class="form-control discount" id="discount_1" step="0.00" min="0" /></td>

      <td><input type="number" name='total[]' class="form-control total" id="total_1" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='addr1'></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and provide the HTML too

Comment: Ok bro, thanks for answer, i added HTML codes too..

Comment: I think you need to delegate proper. And make sure to use unique IDs and classes to access added fields

Comment: Second script is dealing with only one id just to calculate, and class name doing the rest. But i am sure, both script have Add more field feature so its creating problem, I have lack of knowledge about Javascript so couldn't figure it out, any help will be appreciated..